# EAR and EJB classloader error with Overthere

Tags: java, classloader, ejb-3.0, netweaver

I`m developing client that uses library Overthere 2.3.1. With local machine client works perfectly. But when I try to call same code included to EJB 3.0, I've got exception that not all required classes have been loaded.

I`ve looked over the source and found that the class contains Protocol annotation scanner (https://github.com/hierynomus/scannit) with hardcoded class name:

```
Scannit scannit = new Scannit(Configuration.config()
     .scan("com.xebialabs")
     .with(new AbstractScanner[] { new TypeAnnotationScanner() }));
```

The command

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("com/xebialabs")
```

returns null.

Looks like EJB runs in a separate classloader which does not have access to all the jars.

The EJB is packed to EAR with following structure:

```
EAR    
--META-INF    
----sda-dd.xml
----SAP_MANIFEST.MF
----MANIFEST.MF  
----application-j2ee-engine.xml    
--ejb.jar    
--extlibs.jars
```

The `MANIFEST.MF` file don`t contain any reference to external libs in CLASS-PATH. The EAR project is deployed to Application server successfully.

The `EJB.jar` also contains `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with value `"Class-Path: ."` by default.

I`ve already tried playing around with CLASS-PATH in manifest files, but have no luck.

Could anyone help me, how to build project with all external libs to be loaded while EJB runs? What have I missed with resources and classloaders?

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: The application server is SAP Netweaver 7.4

Comment: Nope, haven't worked with that one. But on most application servers jars should be placed in a sub directory "lib" within the ear.  Maybe this is the cause?

Comment: Where exactly is the 'Overthere' jar anyway? Is it in the root of the EAR together with your ejb.jar? If so, do what sergey says; put the dependency jars in a lib subdirectory. NOT the ejb.jar, only the dependency jars.

Comment: The Overthere jar is in the root of EAR togerger with ejb.jar. I`ve already tried to relocate dependency jars to lib - same error.It`s quite strange, that all resourses are found during ejb call, no NoClassDefFoundError exception occurs. However inner scan of resourses returns null.